# Access SQL Inventory, Products with multiple orders counting more than once

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL Query which shows the inventory status before any orders in or out:

```
SELECT Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand,
  Nz(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]),0) AS Outgoing, Nz(Sum([Query1.Quantity]),0) AS Incoming,
  [OnHand]+[Outgoing]-[Incoming] AS OnHandAfter, [StandardCost]*[OnHandAfter] AS TotalCost
FROM Query3
GROUP BY Query3.Products.ID, Query3.ProductName, Query3.StandardCost, Query3.OnHand;
```

And then I've tried to filter it so it accepts a user-inputted date to back-track stock status to:

```
SELECT Q1.Products.ID, 
 Q1.ProductName, 
 Q1.StandardCost, 
 Q1.OnHand, 
 SUM([Q1.OnHand] + [Q2_sub.Outgoing] - [Q3_sub.Incoming]) AS OnHandAfter, 
 ([Q1.StandardCost] * [OnHandAfter]) AS TotalCost
FROM (
 Query3 AS Q1 
      LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT Q2.Products.ID, 
                Q2.ProductName, 
                Q2.StandardCost, 
                Q2.OnHand, 
                NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]), 0) AS Outgoing 
           FROM Query3 AS Q2 
           WHERE (
                     (
                         (ShippedDate) > [Enter End Date]
                         OR (ShippedDate) IS NULL
                         )
                     )
           GROUP BY Q2.Products.ID, 
                Q2.ProductName, 
                Q2.StandardCost, 
                Q2.OnHand)  AS Q2_Sub ON Q1.Products.ID = Q2_Sub.ID) 
      LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT Q3.Products.ID, 
                     Q3.ProductName, 
                     Q3.StandardCost, 
                     Q3.OnHand, 
                     NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]), 0) AS Incoming
                FROM Query3 AS Q3 
                WHERE (
                     (
                         (DateReceived) > [Enter End Date]
                         OR (DateReceived) IS NULL
                      )
                 ) 
                GROUP BY Q3.Products.ID, 
                     Q3.ProductName, 
                     Q3.StandardCost, 
                     Q3.OnHand)  AS Q3_Sub ON Q1.Products.ID = Q3_Sub.ID
GROUP BY Q1.Products.ID, Q1.ProductName, Q1.StandardCost, Q1.OnHand;
```

**It appears some results are doubling up in the Outgoing/Incoming columns. The thing the products that are doubling up have in common are they've all been ordered on two occasions. (i.e. the coffee has been ordered once for 25 and once for 5, but comes up as 60.) Some have also doubled their On Hand values, such as the Crab Meat example below. How do I fix it from counting them both twice?**

Ex. 1: What it should be

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost |
| 14 | Crab Meat    | £13.80        | 185     | 23       | 0        | 208         | £2,870.40
```

What it comes to

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost
| 14 | Crab Meat    | £13.80        | 185     | 46       | 0        | 416         | £5,106.00
```

---

Ex. 2: What it should be

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost |
| 16 | Coffee       | £34.50        | 150     | 30       | 152      | 28          | £966.00
```

What it comes to

```
| ID | Product Name | Standard Cost | On Hand | Outgoing | Incoming | OnHandAfter | TotalCost
| 16 | Coffee       | £34.50        | 150     | 60       | 304      | 46          | £1,587.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical Cartesian Join issue.  If you have multiple dates and you don't use Date in your GROUP BY statement, you're going to get one record for every date.  Which means if you have 2 dates it will double, 3 dates and it will triple, etc...  You're going to have to work out the SQL to include the Date field that's causing this.

I know this sounds like a daunting task, but what I always do in cases like this are take one query as a time.  i.e., first work out:

```
       SELECT Q2.Products.ID, 
            Q2.ProductName, 
            Q2.StandardCost, 
            Q2.OnHand, 
            NZ(Sum([OrderJoin.Quantity]), 0) AS Outgoing 
       FROM Query3 AS Q2 
       WHERE (
                 (
                     (ShippedDate) > [Enter End Date]
                     OR (ShippedDate) IS NULL
                 )
             )
       GROUP BY Q2.Products.ID, 
            Q2.ProductName, 
            Q2.StandardCost, 
            Q2.OnHand
```

then work out the next piece:

```
            SELECT Q3.Products.ID, 
                 Q3.ProductName, 
                 Q3.StandardCost, 
                 Q3.OnHand, 
                 NZ(Sum([Query1.Quantity]), 0) AS Incoming
            FROM Query3 AS Q3 
            WHERE (
                     (
                        (DateReceived) > [Enter End Date]
                        OR (DateReceived) IS NULL
                     )
                  ) 
            GROUP BY Q3.Products.ID, 
                 Q3.ProductName, 
                 Q3.StandardCost, 
                 Q3.OnHand
```

then work out the "big picture" piece.  Trying to do it all in one lump almost always makes your job harder.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it's because in `Query3` as referenced, it outer joins the products to purchases. However since they are on different dates I would still need to distinguish between them, so I need to find a way to stop them joining before the date is checked, and join them after